# Tell heroku which config file for Play application to load

Tags: heroku, playframework

In Play, you can use multiple config files (application.conf, prod.conf...). Usually you would have a default conf file, i.e. application.conf, and let the other files import it and overload specific values.

One case is for example when you have a production database and wand to overwrite access configuration values set by developers and use credentials only known to the production personnel.

Here is [a manual on this topic](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration#specifying-alternative-configuration-file) that say that the wanted config is to be specified as a parameter when running the application
I am deploying my application onto Heroku, which takes care of running the application. The only peace missing here and I can't find is how to tell Heroku which config file to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) with the contents:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/my_app -Dhttp.port=$PORT -Dconfig.resource=my-special.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define environment variables for your Heroku app, e.g. using the heroku config CLI command:

```
heroku config:set PLAY_CONFIG_FILE=application.conf
```

See [Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect.